# Making routes in React maintainable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router with paths. Currently we have an enum with paths like:

```
enum Paths {
    home: '/home',
    finding: '/finding',
}
```

and I create links "manually" like so:

```
navigate(`${Paths.home}${Paths.finding}`)
```

This works but is not maintainable at all.

My other idea was:

```
paths: {
  path: '/',
  home: {
    path: '/home',
      finding: {
        path: '/finding',
        params: {
          id: string
        },
        edit: {
          path: '/edit'
        }
      }
  }
}

navigate(paths.home.finding)
```

but this quickly falls apart, since my routes are `home/finding/id/edit` and I'd need to throw a wildcard into an object/break it apart. So not maintainable.

I think the best solution is to simply keep the routes one under the other with similar parts shared like:

```
userBase = '/home'
userFinding = `${userBase}/finding/id`
userFindingEdit = `${userFinding}/edit`
```

But this is kind of pointless with nested Routes.

```
<Route path={Paths.home} element={...}>
  <Route path={Paths.finding}>
    <Route path={Paths.id}>
      <Route path={Paths.edit} element={<EditFinding />} />
      <Route path={Paths.empty} element={<Finding />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

If there was a way to extract all possible routes combination from react router with a hook that would be perfect. Do you have any other suggestions?

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-frost-pjhkmd?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Do you mean something like the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#useroutes) hook that is passed a routes config array? What are you really trying to accomplish here? What does "maintainable routes" mean?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to be able to pass a correct route to each link/navigate function. So that I don't duplicate the concatenation like `${home}/${finding}/${id}/${edit}`. Say I change it to home/finding/edit/id. I now have to go through all the code mentions and find strings to change. I want to avoid this problem

Comment: Your question seems to be more about how to create and maintain link paths and not so much the route definitions. Can you edit the post to include the relevant code you are using to generate links?

Comment: I edited. It's under "and I create links "manually" like so:"

Comment: RRDv6 is capable of using both absolute and relative paths. What sort of links are you trying to generate or use in the app? One may be easier to use in certain circumstances. IMO you are overcomplicating things a bit, but it's hard to say without seeing a more representative [mcve] to see exactly the sorts of routes you are rendering and what links you are trying to use, and how.

Comment: I added an example. I hope this clears things up https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-frost-pjhkmd?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. The sandbox also wasn't running since it was missing imports and usage of the `Routes` component to handle route matching. I fixed this part, but then there were issues nesting `"/"` routes under relative paths. I also fixed this, but then there's nothing else. I suspect you are trying to build absolute paths from the root and pass these down to nested routed components. My statement regarding use of absolute and relative paths still applies, but I can't see really how you are trying to manage much.